# Error de enrutamiento a la hora de Paginar con flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask, paginación, sqlalchemy

Tengo el siguiente problema, estoy tratando de paginar el resultado que me arroja una base de datos, si lo hago con all() excelente, pero cuando quiero usar paginate me arroja el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estuve leyendo que colocara localhost/personas/page_num=1 pero cuando lo hago asi me arroja error 404

Mi codigo

```
@personas.route("/personas/<int:page_num>/", methods=['GET'])
def tabla_personas(page_num):
    personasDB = PersonasData.query.paginate(per_page=2, page=page_num, error_out=True)
    return render_template("/tablas/personas.html/", personasDB=personasDB)
```

En el HTML:

```
{% for persona in personasDB.items %}
    <div class="card-body">
      <table class="table table-hover table-bordered ">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="col-4">Correo</th>
            <td>{{persona.email}} - {{persona.email2}}</td>
          </tr>
{% endfor %}
```